# Koala Facebook api call sometimes returning 500 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala

Basically, I'm trying to grab a user's photo albums from Facebook and display them with a cover photo.

In my Users Controller I have:

```
def facebook(token)
  @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(token)
end

def get_photo_albums
  albums = self.facebook.get_connection(uid, "albums")
  albums.map { |h| { id: h["id"], name: h["name"], count: h["count"], cover_photo: self.facebook.get_picture(h["cover_photo"]) } }
end
```

This code works fine most of the time, but occasionally I get the following error:

```
Koala::Facebook::APIError (HTTP 500: Response body: {"error":{"message":"No node specified","type":"Exception"}}):
app/models/user.rb:79:in `block in albums'
app/models/user.rb:79:in `map'
app/models/user.rb:79:in `albums'
```

My app is on canvas and I get a new access token by parsing the signed_request everytime a user visits the app, which should last 2 hours.

I can't figure out why this error is appearing for some users as it works fine most of the time? Any ideas or suggestions to improve this code will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and it seems to happen if there is no photo / cover_photo within the response.

```
, cover_photo: fb_cover_photo(h) } }
```

I used this rescue statement:

```
def fb_cover_photo(photo)
    begin
      self.facebook.get_picture(photo["cover_photo"])
    rescue Exception => e
      nil
    end     
end
```